# Pythonic way to pad list1 with non-redundant members from list2?

Tags: python, list

`list1` starts with 0–5 members and needs to end with exactly 5 members. If it has less than 5 members, I want to append non-redundant values from `list2`, which is always the same. For example:

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
-------------------
output: [2,3,1,4,5]
```

```
list1 = [1,2,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
-------------------
output: [1,2,5,3,4]
```

Right now I'm doing it this way:

```py
i = 0
while len(list1) < 5:
    if list2[i] not in list1:
        list1.append(list2[i])
    i += 1
```

which works, but it doesn't seem very Pythonic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sample input, expected output, minimal reproducible code sample, stack trace, error etc please!

Comment: @LazyCoder the code I provided works, I'm just asking if there's an alternative structure I should be using.

Comment: does order matter ?

Comment: @prashantrana yes, otherwise I would use sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use list1 and add elements from list2 if they are not already in list1 until list1 has 5 elements.

```
list1 + [el for el in list2 if el not in list1][:5-len(list1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more pythonic way to do it (at least with no apparent for) using list comprehensions:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,4,3,5]

# We remove all the elements in l2 that are already in l1
l2 = [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]

# We fill l1 with elements from l2 depending on the length of l1
l1 = l1 + [x for x in l2[0:5-len(l1)]]
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: it's a way but not so pythonic, you need to modify l2 first then add it in l1 , too much task, in this process you loose l2 originality , i think OP way is good enough and pythonic

Answer (score 0):

If order is important, you can use `sorted()`:

```
list1 = [2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

list1 = sorted(list2, key=lambda k: k not in list1)

print(list1)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @pythonic833 You have right, I've read OP comments afterwards. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

readability is more emphasized  in python, if your code is not good to read and understand,need to write it again [some rule to write python code](https://docs.python-guide.org/intro/learning/)

```
list1 = [1,2,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in list2:
    if i not in list1 and len(list1)<5:
        list1.append(i)
```